# 2 unique columns mysql

Tags: mysql, unique

How do I make it so 2 columns cannot have the same data. My table consists of 3 fields.

```
studentid    id_project     level_of_want
1            2                high
1            3                low
1            4                high
1            2                low
```

I want is so that one column can have the same data (eg 1 in `studentid`) but the `studentid` and `id_project` cannot have the same data more than once (enties 1 and 4 above). `studentid` can be 1 and `id_project` can be 1, but this can only happen once.

Comment: You can do it with a trigger, before insert if col1= col2 don't insert, I have to go so I'll help you tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an "unique" index.

Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

```
create unique index my_index on my_table (studentid, id_project);
```

Comment: @jcho360 I don't see what you mean. If he wants to avoid couples like rows 1 and 4 he really needs this unique constraint.

Comment: Looks like the solution to me - not sure why this wouldn't do what the OP asked for?

Comment: unique index could be (1,1) or (2,2), that's unique but he doesn't want that.

Comment: To be fair I had a minute of doubt reading the question. This kind of things isn't always easily written without ambiguity.